# Enabling https to Xampp localhost

Tags: apache, ssl, https, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to enable `https` to localhost on my local device, I searched about it, but nothing worked.

I made sure that these are enabled:

In `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

In `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

I added this to `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" 
    ServerName localhost:443 
    ServerAlias localhost:443  
    SSLEngine on 
    SSLCertificateFile "/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/conf/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I tried:

```
SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key"
```

But I get:

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Subject: localhost

Issuer: localhost

Expires on: Nov 9, 2019

Current date: Oct 27, 2018

PEM encoded chain:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----



This server could not prove that it is localhost;
its security certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system.
This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

As well as changing the listen to `443` in `httpd.conf`

After editing the `listen` in `httpd.conf` to `443`, I get errors running `apache`:

```
 Diese Eingabeforderung nicht waehrend des Running beenden
Bitte erst bei einem gewollten Shutdown schliessen
Please close this command only for Shutdown
Apache 2 is starting ...
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443

(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:
443
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Apache konnte nicht gestartet werden
Apache could not be started
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What the result is? Apache starts? Any error messages?

Comment: @SvenLiivak, After changing the `listen` in `httpd.conf` to `443` I can't open localhost

Answer (score 2):

At first you don't have to edit the `Listen` statement in the file `httpd.conf`. You can and should leave it like that:

```
Listen 80
```

The rest of your configuration looks good and **is working fine**. The problem or the reason why you are getting the error message you desribed is because you are using a self-signed certificate. This self-signed certificate hasn't a valid authority (a company which validates your certificate).

For test-purpose on a local system this is absolute valid. But if you want to force your browser *(I can see you're using Google Chrome from the message you posted)* to trust the certificate you have to import your self-signed certificate to the list of trusted certificates. A good tutorial was posted by @kellen in this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15076602/6694684).